# Implement a nice one autoresize mechanism for Listview columns?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listview, resize

I would like to add a decent `AutoResize` mechanism to my Listview but I don't know what to do.

I set the last column to Autoresize itselfs when the Form resizes:

```
Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles MyBase.Resize

    ColumnDownload.AutoResize(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)

End Sub
```

But this native autoresize method is so wrong because when I resize the application, the horizontal scrollbar is shown:

[image]

[image]

Ofcourse If I pick by myself with the mouse the last column separator to increase the column width then I want to see/use the horizontal scrollbar, but the framework autoresize just autoincreases the size displaying that horizontal scrollbar, is so ugly an uneficient there's no need to auto display that scrollbar when resizing the form!

The look that I would is just like JDownloader and all the nice programs has, an Autoresize that stops exactly on the start of the vertical scrollbar without showing the ugly horizontal scrollbar if not needed, for example like this:

[image]

I hope that you could understand my question.

> EDIT:

'*Magic solutions*' such as these:

```
MyColumnHeader.Width = -2
MyColumnHeader.Width = -1
```

...Does the same. See good article here: http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/ListViewQT.htm

Really all the Google search results about resizing a Listview in .NET are using that, any proportional resize or alternative, any decent auto resizer, incredible.

Comment: write code to resize each column proportional to the control's new width **less** the width of the vertical scroll.  OnSizeChanged maybe, reset each column width then call Invalidate.  probably also need a `rectOldSize` to be able to do the proportional part.

Comment: how are these resized when you resize the app?  are using a TableLayoutPanel or gobs of code?  I have a procedure for when VScrolls appear, but I am not sure if that is what you are after (or if it works with a TLP or what a TLP does to colum widths).

Comment: `how are these resized when you resize the app?` I've detailed the (weird) method that I use to resize the last column, also I've shown the aspect of the `LV` when I resize the app in the images above, all the necessary info is in the question, there is no more code about that. I'm not using a `TLP`, I'm using the `Anchor` property to resize the `LV` when the Form is resized. I think a function to know when a `VSCroll` appears can't help me for anything, a perfect solution (dreaming is free) could be the code that uses `ObjectListView` to proportional resize translated for generic use.

Comment: the only Use-Case I can see is `when I resize the application`.  If you drag the header, scrolls appear *because the columns no longer fit* inside the LV.  If you shrink the app with an LV anchored on all sides, the scrolls appear *because the columns no longer fit*. It would take some doing to distinguish one from the other (and why???).  I have code to AutoResize to suppress the HScroll just because the VScroll popped up, and it seems semi-related at least in the pics, but that seems not to be what you are after.

Comment: What happens when there is not enough space for all columns? do you want them do be divided proportionally in the grid? do you want just the last column to be reduced?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html), a open source wrapper around a .NET ListView, has a `FillsFreeSpace` property which does exactly this.

As the user resizes the control, the column will become larger or smaller, such that the horizontal scroll bar is never shown. It was relatively complicated to implement correctly :)

See [this link](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html?highlight=fillsfreespace#how-can-i-make-a-column-get-bigger-when-the-objectlistview-is-made-bigger) for more details.

[Edit]

Basic scheme:

1. Listen for `Resize` event on the ListView.
2. Calculate the width of all columns except the last
3. Resize the last column to the difference of the width of the other columns and the `ClientSize` of the ListView.

This will work:

```
private void ResizeLastColumn(int listViewWidth)
{
    int totalColumnWidth = 0;
    for (int i =0 ; i < listView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++) {
        totalColumnWidth += listView1.Columns[i].Width;
    }

    colLast.Width = Math.Max(listViewWidth - totalColumnWidth, 10);
}

private void listView1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ResizeLastColumn(this.listView1.ClientSize.Width);
}
```

The limitation on this is that the horizontal scroll bar will flicker slightly when shrinking the control. To get around *that*, you need to intercept the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message, and resize the columns to the size that the control is *going* to become. This is somewhat complicated -- and exactly what ObjectListView does :)

Comment: I appreciate the information but sorry is not a viable approach for me, Using ObjectListView means writing a 1000 lines model class Just to add 1 string item to a ListView, and to replace all my written Listview things to translate them to the ObjectListview. Also I'm using a custom listview user control designed by me,just I can't use that,has any of easy for any kind of project.By the way in the source I've tried to find the FillsFreeSpace methods to understand and reproduce/copy them but the C# code is too much complex C# and I'm a VBNET programmer I only know the basics of C#. thanks again